Unit conversion of q point (from iku to 1/a.u.) in yambo
Here are some necessary info about direct lattice and reciprocal lattice from yambo output file:
   Alat factors          :  10.16964  10.16964  10.16964 [a.u.]
      Direct lattice volume :   2103.52    [a.u.]
      Direct lattice vectors:  A[ 1 ]  A[ 2 ]  A[ 3 ]
       A[ 1 ]:  1.000000  1.000000  0.000000  [iru]
       10.16964  10.16964   0.00000  [cc]
       A[ 2 ]:  0.000000  1.000000  1.000000  [iru]
        0.00000  10.16964  10.16964  [cc]
       A[ 3 ]:  1.000000  0.000000  1.000000  [iru]
       10.16964   0.00000  10.16964  [cc]
    
      Recip. lattice volume :  0.117921 [a.u.]
      Recip. lattice vectors:  B[ 1 ]  B[ 2 ]  B[ 3 ]
       B[ 1 ]:  0.500000  0.500000 -0.500000  [iku]
       0.308919  0.308919 -0.308919  [cc]
       B[ 2 ]: -0.500000  0.500000  0.500000  [iku]
      -0.308919  0.308919  0.308919  [cc]
       B[ 3 ]:  0.500000 -0.500000  0.500000  [iku]
       0.308919 -0.308919  0.308919  [cc]

iku refers "internal k-point units" and cc means the atomic units. In yambo, we can calculate dielectric function on a particular q point (point in a 1st BZ, momentum). In the output, I have seen the q points are in iku units. How can I convert the q point to atomic unit (a.u)?
For example the point shows as follows:
# Absorption @ Q(3): 0.166666657 -0.166666657 0.166666657 [iku]

Would anyone suggest me how can I convert it from iku to 1/a.u?

You can convert the q-points from Yambo's internal k-units ($\mathbf{q}^{\mathrm{iku}}$) to the k-points in cartesian coordinates ($\mathbf{k}^{\mathrm{cc}}$) of Quantum Espresso (QE) using:
$\mathbf{k}^{\mathrm{cc}}_x = \frac{2\pi}{a_x} \, \mathbf{q}^{\mathrm{iku}}_x$,
analogously for $y$ and $z$.
Here, $a_x$ is the lattice constant scaling factor given in the r_setup file of yambo under alat_x that can also be governed from the reciprocal lattice vector matrix, by normalizing the entries along the axis $x,y$ and $z$.
See this Yambo forum post.
